# Using Beautiful Soup for parsing NELL Knowlege Base page

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm using Beautiful Soup to parse list of categories from http://rtw.ml.cmu.edu/rtw/kbbrowser/, and I got the html code of this page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="../css/browser.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (parent.location.href == self.location.href) {
                if (window.location.href.replace)
                    window.location.replace('index.php');
                else
                    // causes problems with back button, but works
                    window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="ontology">
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using quite simple code, but when I'm trying to get to the `<body>` element, I get `None`:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize
from mechanize import Browser
import requests
import re
import os

link = 'http://rtw.ml.cmu.edu/rtw/kbbrowser/ontology.php'
pageFile = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageFile)

print soup.head.contents[0].name
print soup.html.contents[1].name
```

Why does the head element in this case not have a sibling?
I'm getting:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_element'

when trying to get `head.next_Sibling` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because *text nodes* are also a part of `contents`.

Instead of operating the `contents` property, use [`CSS selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to locate the list of categories. For example, here is how you can list top-level categories:

```
for li in soup.select("body#ontology > ul > li"):
    print li.find_all("a")[-1].text
```

Comment: @MaximRukhlov yeah, there are multiple ways to locate elements in `BeautifulSoup`. The reason I pointed you to CSS selectors is that I'm pretty sure this is what is going to help you to parse the list of categories.